# Slide show and animation iOS

Tags: ios, animation, uiimage, slideshow

[image: Slide show]

I need to create a slideshow as above. There are 5 screens from left to right in the picture above
1) In the first screen: All picture is tilted
2) When I swipe, the first picture moving along with my finger and finally move to the back of the queue. The second picture comes up.

Can anyone give me some source to read and practice to do these tasks?

EDIT: For those who choose to use iCarousel and need to add an action when user tap to an image which is currently chosen:
Add the following to your ViewController.
    - (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
    {
        if( index == carousel.currentItemIndex )
        {
            //Define your action here
        }
    }
Hope it helps someone!

Comment: +1 for the Nice question, but did you tried anything ?

Comment: I searched and tried some sources, for example http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html, reading some tutorials on Three20 but I didn't find anything similar to what I need

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good start, iCarousel > https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: Thanks. I tried Examples/Storyboard Demo and I think it is suitable for me. I still have one question: How I add an action to a picture which is currently focused? For example, tap on the picture to view the picture in full mode? Is this a good tutorial of iCarousel or could you please recommend some tutorials: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-creating-an-awesome-carousel/